# Error: Azure VM not obtaining Fabric URI

Tags: azure, windows-server

I recently purchased an Azure VM with Server 2012 R2 on it. At this point I could go to the IP & the domain of the server and a webpage would resolve. After we installed ConnectWise we could no longer see the webpage resolving. Here are the errors I am getting from Azure:

> Did not discover fabric address on any interface. Dumping networking
> information.
>
> Failed to obtain fabric URI. ControlSystem not
> initialized.

What could this possibly mean? I have never heard of this in my life.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like ConnectWise has modified the virtual NIC in a way that is unsupported by Azure.  See http://windowsitpro.com/azure/fix-rdp-azure-virtual-machine for instructions on getting this fixed:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName <service> -Name <vm> | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension | Update-AzureVM
```

And https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/538a8f18-7c1f-4d6e-b81c-70c00e25c93d/troubleshooting-endpoint-connectivity-rdpsshhttp-etc-failures?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I am still able to RDP into the machine fine, however the IP/Domain do not resolve anymore.

There is no firewall active at the moment and anti-virus has been turned off for troubleshooting purposes. There is no conflict from these two.

We have resized the VM since the install, in hopes that would alleviate the problem, but it has not.

Comment: Is there a way to repair the virtual NIC without redeploying the server?

Comment: Either of the last 2 options (Resize VM, Recreate VM from image) in the second link from the answer should do this.

Comment: Okay, I am recreating the VM. Thank you.